# History API | How to listen to forward() events

Tags: javascript, browser-history

**TL;DR - Is there a way to listen to `forward()` events of the history API?**

I'm trying to handle navigation events in my application (to attach data for each route and support back & forward navigation).

I achieve this by saving the data in a stack object that aims to replicate the browser's history.

Currently, I use the history API to listen to `onpopstate` events, and for any new browsing events.

Now I need to be able to differentiate between events fired due to forward vs. event that were just routed.
Is that even possible? Do the browser export such an API?

Comment: You could use the History State, set a flag that it's been visited, if it's not then you know it was just routed.  You could even work out if backwards and forwards by mixing localeStorage and History state and using counters..